# How to create a class that will replace the existing java class?

Tags: java, oop, class, inheritance

I need to create a class that will replace the existing class in jdk.

i.e. For eg. I want to create a class as NewFile that can replace the java.io.File .
By replace I mean not to replace in jdk but to to give it a new implement in my own package but it should be used as existing java.io.File .

Will extending java.io.File helps or any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just extend it and it will gain all the behaviour of java.io.file. You will then be free to add new behaviour to it, and change behaviour by overiding methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you don't want to extend any functionality, you don't need to do it. If you are doing it for fun, you can extend it and use it. However, if a class is `final`, you cannot extend it.

Answer (score -1):

Create your class and put it before jdk jar in classpath. Your class will be picked instead of jdk class.